# How to make an empty object in swift

Tags: swift, object

How do I initialize an empty object in swift? This is what I have but it wants the parameters too

```
var userInfo:User = User()

init(email: String, isVerified: String, profileImageURL: String, reputation: String, twitterHandle: String, userName: String) {
        self._email = email
        self._isVerified = isVerified
        self._profileImageURL = profileImageURL
        self._reputation = reputation
        self._twitterHandle = twitterHandle
        self._userName = userName
    }
```

Comment: What does the object definition look like? What's the init function?

Comment: I've just been initializing it with empty strings

Comment: @ShedSports I don't know the specifics of your application, but I guarantee you that a user consisting of an e-mail, username, etc. initialized to empty strings and other nonsensical values is... non-sensical. What you have isn't an "empty" object, it's an "object that's technically possible to be created, but represents absolutely nothing of value in my business domain, and which should therefore be made impossible to exist". If you share more about the underlying problem you're trying to solve, I may be able to suggest alternatives

Comment: Why do you wish to create an "empty" user object? What's the benefit? Why not do `var userInfo: User?` and leave it as a nil optional?

Answer (score 12):

Create the class/struct with optional properties like this

```
struct Employee {//struct or class
    var name: String?
    var number: String?
    var position: String?
}
```

Then you can create an object without any value, with some value

```
let emp = Employee()
let emp = Employee(name: nil, number: nil, position: nil)
let emp = Employee(name: "abc", number: nil, position: "xyz")
```

By creating a init method with default values parameter can be ignored while creating an object

```
struct Employee {
    var name: String?
    var number: String?
    var position: String?
    init(name: String? = nil, number: String? = nil, position: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.position = position
    }
}
let emp = Employee()
let emp = Employee(name: "abc", number: "124", position: "xyz")
let emp = Employee(name: "abc", position: "xyz")
let emp = Employee(number: "124")
let emp = Employee(name: "abc", number: "124")
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are creating empty User objects so that the information can be filled in later on. There are two problems I can see with this: **one**, object properties will all have to be variables and **second**, it's easy to make mistakes and pass the wrong information since the object does not always correspond to a real entity.

A better approach would be to define a set of parameters that are mandatory for a User object to be defined, and let every other parameters either be optional parameters, or give them default values. For example, if we choose username and email to be mandatory, and let profile image be optional, and isVerified to have a default value of false:

```
class User {
    var userName: String
    var email: String
    var isVerified: Bool
    var profileImageURL: String?

    init(userName: String, email: String, isVerified: Bool = false) {
        self.userName = userName
        self.email = email
        self.isVerified = isVerified
    } 
}
```